# How to create a new membership user via Ektron CMS400.NET web service API?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ektron

I am attempting to create new membership users in an Ektron CMS400.NET-based website by through calls to the User web service API from a remote site. One of the methods I intend to utilize, [AddMembershipUser](http://www.ektron.com/manuals/cms400/v70/API_Help/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Ektron_Services_User_AddMembershipUser@UserData.html) has a remark in the documentation indicating "A user with administrator privileges must be logged in to perform this operation.". I am already providing the necessary credentials via the AuthenticationHeaderValue object for calling the web service remotely. I have also made a call to the [LogInUser](http://www.ektron.com/manuals/cms400/v70/API_Help/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Ektron_Services_User_LogInUser@string@string@string@string@string.html) method, to login one of my admin users, and this appears to be working. The point at which I am stuck is figuring out how to execute the call to AddMembershipUser as the admin user whom I just logged in. I have requests out to Ektron support, and have been searching both the forums and documentation, but have yet to find any answers.

Does anyone have examples of calling web service API methods as a programmatically logged in user, from a remote server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this with Ektron 6.13,6.15,6.18,7.03 and 7.04, in each version they radically changed/broke the API in many different and interesting ways. I can give you an answer for each of those versions, but my advice is to put a membership control on a page and use that to create a user while logging the SQL that happens with SQL profiler (also any other logging/inspection techniques you can think of). Then try the API methods and see how the API is doing it and compare the two, there's usually huge differences in the versions I've experienced. For most of the cases I've had to deal with, I've had to let the API do its partial job and then go directly to the database to update the record correctly.

Comment: Just noticed this is an old question, I suspect you possibly might have got an answer from Ektron by now.

Comment: The particular site feature that would have required creating new membership users ended up getting canceled. The response from Ektron didn't arrive in time to make a difference - by then, we had already gone a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can make of their documentation you should be able to make the call as long as you path the login credentials via the AuthenicationheaderValue object.  You might need to call login first as well, it is possible they are tracking session on their side somehow.